# Regular expression using jQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am writing a script (where on click) will show the output of the checkbox that has been clicked. So far this is working correctly. the output is the label of the checkbox that has been checked, for example, hello 123,

I would like the output to show just the words and not the numbers. I know this would be done with a regular expression, but have never used regular expression in javascript before, and not sure how to go about it. Any help would be grateful

```
jQuery('#container').on('click', '#inputID', function() {
  if (jQuery(this).is(':checked')) {
    console.debug('checked:', jQuery(this).next().text()); 
  } else { 
    console.debug('unchecked:', jQuery(this).next().text());
  };
});
```

Thanks

Comment: `console.debug('checked:', jQuery(this).next().text().match(/[a-z]/i)[0]); `

Comment: Amazing, I didnt even think of using .match. Thank you

Comment: i think it's `[a-z]+`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `match` function.

```
console.debug('checked:', jQuery(this).next().text().match(/[a-z]+/i)[0]);
```

`[a-z]+` would match one or more letters. `i` modifier helps to do a case-insensitive match. By default `match` returns the output as array. So by accessing the index `0` will give you the first elemnt.